# Selecionar coluna de um data.frame --- divisão de Base de Dados em R

Tags: r, data.frame

Eu importei uma tabela como base de dados para tratar em R. No entanto, preciso fazer alguns cálculos com apenas algumas colunas dessa tabela.

Como faço para selecionar apenas essas colunas para os cálculos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existem várias formas de selecionar colunas de um `data.frame` no R, vamos usar como exemplo o `data.frame` `mtcars`. Para saber quais colunas existem, você pode pedir para ver os `names` ou `colnames` do `data.frame`:

```
names(mtcars)
 [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
```

Para selecionar alguma dessas colunas, por exemplo, a coluna `mpg`,  você pode usar o `$mpg`, o colchetes `[,"mpg"]` como se fosse uma matriz, ou o duplo colchetes como se fosse uma lista `[["mpg"]]`:

```
mtcars$mpg
mtcars[, "mpg"]
mtcars[["mpg"]]
```

**Essas três formas mencionadas retornam um vetor como resultado.** Você também pode *selecionar um data.frame contendo a coluna `mpg`* (note a diferença, você recebe um data.frame e não um vetor). Para tanto você vai usar o colchete simples como se fosse um lista:

```
mtcars["mpg"]
```

Ou também usar a foram de matriz, com o argumento `drop = FALSE`.

```
mtcars[ ,"mpg", drop = FALSE]
```

Se você quiser selecionar mais de uma coluna, você pode usar tanto o colchete simples como lista quanto o colchete simples como matriz.

```
mtcars[ ,c("mpg", "cyl")] # seleciona duas colunas
mtcars[c("mpg", "cyl")] # seleciona duas colunas
```

Note que agora a forma de matriz te retorna um `data.frame`, já que você está selecionando mais de uma coluna. Existem funções de conveniência para fazer isso também, como a função `subset` que o rafael mencionou. Ela vai te retornar um data.frame com a coluna `mpg` e não um vetor:

```
subset(mtcars, select = c("mpg","cyl"))
```

E cada pacote de manipulação de dados também tem sua forma de selecionar colunas. Por exemplo, o `dplyr` tem a função select, que é bem parecido com o subset mencionado:

```
mtcars %>% select(mpg, cyl)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ficaria mais fácil se você incluísse a sua base de dados (ou alguma parte dela) para que pudéssemos trabalhar em cima dela. Dê uma olhada na função `dput` para esse fim. Também seria legal se você incluísse o código que você desenvolveu / tentou desenvolver.

Quanto a sua dúvida, as funções `subset`, da própria base do `R`, ou a função `select`, do pacote `dplyr`, devem te auxiliar.